# JSON flatter for list

Tags: python, json, dataframe, api

I get info from API in json format, but it is nested. In order to flatten json, I used this function. The info would later go to dataframe:

```
def flattenjson(b, delim):
    val = {}
    for i in b.keys():
        if isinstance(b[i], dict):
            get = flattenjson(b[i], delim)
            for j in get.keys():
                val[i + delim + j] = get[j]
    
        else:
            val[i] = b[i]
            
    return val
```

This works only for dict instances:

```
flattenjson({
    "pk": 22, 
    "model": "auth.permission", 
    "fields": {
      "codename": "add_message", 
      "name": "Can add message", 
      "content_type": 8
    }
  }, "__")
```

and result of this is:

```
{
    "pk": 22, 
    "model": "auth.permission", 
    "fields__codename": "add_message", 
    "fields__name": "Can add message", 
    "fields__content_type": 8
}
```

But here is where the problem comes. From API I get this result:

```
{
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "normalized": [
        {
          "hotWater": [
            {
              "G1": "None",
              "G2": "None",
              ...
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and when getting it through the same function I get this:

```
{'response__data__normalized': [{'hotWater': [{'G1': 'None',
     'G2': 'None',
     ...}]}]}
```

where's I would like to look like this:

```
{'response__data__normalized': [{'response__data__normalized_hotWater'
   [{'response__data__normalized_hotWater_G1': 'None',
     'response__data__normalized_hotWater_G2': 'None',
     ...}]}]}
```

or:

```
{ 'normalized': [{'normalized_hotWater': 
       [{'normalized_hotWater_G1': 'None',
         'normalized_hotWater_G2': 'None',
         ...}]}]}
```

The problem is when the function gets to list instances, it either stops or results as the mistake:

```
Input In [69], in flattenjson(b, delim)
      3 def flattenjson(b, delim):
      4     val = {}
----> 5     for i in b.keys():
      6         if isinstance(b[i], dict):
      7             get = flattenjson(b[i], delim)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I am leaning towards the function missing the list format, but dont know how to fix it. would be thankful for any or suggestions ideas, guys!

Comment: Why do you want to flatten your data structure? Is there some other interface you are passing the data to that needs a flattened format?

Comment: @JackTaylor this data later will be formed into csv, and later packed into the clickhouse, in order to get it all, the flatten format is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message is stating, you try to get the `.keys()` of a `list` object, but `.keys()` is actually something you can only do with a `dict`, while the value of the `"normalized"` key of your code is of type `list`.

```
"normalized": [
    {
      "hotWater": [
        {
          "G1": "None",
          "G2": "None",
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Therefore, I would suggest you to check for the type of the object *before* you get the `.keys()`. And then threat the list as in a regular way like:

```
for i in b:
```

Hope this helps!